# If x is real , the numbers $ 5^{1+x} + 5^{1-x} $ , a/2 , $ 25^x + 25^{-x} $ form an A.P. then to which interval must ' a ' belong to?

Tags: sequences-and-series, arithmetic, arithmetic-progressions

A) [ 1 , 5 ]

B) [ 2 , 5 ]

C) [ 5 , 12 ]

D) [ 12 , $ \infty $ ]

My progress so far :

Let  $ 5^{x} = y $

Since they are in AP so ,

=> $ 5y $ + $ 5\over y $ + $ y^2 $ + $ 1\over (y^2)  $ = a

=> $ {5y^3 + 5y + y^4 + 1 }\over (y)^2 $ = a

As you can see , It becomes a mess . How do I solve it with a better approach .

Comment: for any $y \in \mathbb{R^+}$, $y+\frac{1}{y} \ge 2$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For questions like this I try to find useful values of $x$.  The three that immediately suggest themselves to me here are $x=0, x\to +\infty,x \to -\infty$  If $x=0$, we need $10, a/2, 2$ to form an AP, which works with $a=12$.  That rules out two of your choices. Now consider what happens when $x$ is large and positive and again when $x$ is large and negative.

Answer (score 1):

As they are in AP, we have
$$
a = 5^{1+x} + 5^{1-x} + 25^{x} + 25^{-x}.
$$
So say $5^x = t$, then,
$$
a = 5t + \frac{5}{t} + t^2 + \frac{1}{t^2}.
$$
Now 
$$
5t+\frac{5}{t} \geq 10
\qquad\text{and}\qquad
t^2+\frac{1}{t^2} \geq 2
$$
by the AM-GM inequality.

So $a \ge 12$, are the values that $a$ can take.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Refer from Ashwin (IIT Madras).